# Split complex string in several parts

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string

```
a:1:{s:9:"dovclient";a:2:{s:13:"regular_price";s:8:"999";s:13:"selling_price";s:0:"";}}
```

I need to split each such AS this string on 3 parts:

```
$part1 =  a:1:{s:9:"dovclient";a:2:{s:13:"regular_price";s:8:"

$part2 = 999 //price

$part3 = ";s:13:"selling_price";s:0:"";}}
```

PART3 never changes

PART2 is needed value

PART1 after `regular_price";` this `s:8:"` can be `s:6:"` or `s:7:"` (i don't understand logic of it creation) also price ($part2) is variable.

So in final i want to use part 1 and part 3 from each same string but part 2 i want to change. Like

$new_string = `$part1.'2929'.$part3`

Is it possible to split this string as i need?
Or is it another way?

Comment: Do it the correct way http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: @ AbraCadaver It's very similar. One important thing i need to save this construction as i show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a serialized array. This part `s:8:"999"` is incorrect as `s:8` means `string` length `8` but the string `999` is only length `3` so I corrected it to `s:3:"999"`, then use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
$result = unserialize('a:1:{s:9:"dovclient";a:2:{s:13:"regular_price";s:3:"999";s:13:"selling_price";s:0:"";}}');
print_r($result);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [dovclient] => Array
        (
            [regular_price] => 999
            [selling_price] =>
        )

)
```

So access the elements:

```
echo $result['dovclient']['regular_price'];
```

If you want to modify it, `unserialize()` as shown, modify the array as you would any other array and then `serialize()` again.

Comment: Could you give me a recommendation, how to return unserialised string back? I need to write it back in MySQL in serialized type

Comment: You can see the unserialized array.  Modify the array and then serialize it again.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thanks!